# Why can I only select points from only certain strokes? (Grease Pencil)

Tags: grease-pencil

I am a beginner with blender and grease pencil. I don't what I did but all the sudden I couldn't erase, cut or select most of the strokes. For some reason only stroke I have selected could be selected. I have already made sure that those layers are unlocked btw.
[image]

Comment: I suspect that you've somehow switched grease pencil layers.  You can only select on the current layer.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. I not sure what you mean. Is there someway you can help me? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: I somehow figured it out. I actually locked my materials somehow. I feel so stupid now. Thanks for you help!